# How do you pass a variable to SCSS/CSS from HTML's class name?

Tags: html, css, sass

What I want to do is like this

HTML

```
<div class="custom-color--ff0000">Red</div>
<div class="custom-color--00ff00">Green</div>
<div class="custom-color--0000ff">Blue</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-color--(hex) {
  color:  '#' + (hex);
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Would I need Sass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a mixin to generate modifier classes in SASS:

```
@mixin add-color($argument) {
  $string: unquote($argument);

  &--#{$string} {
    color: unquote('#' + $argument);
  }
}
```

example:

```
.custom-color {
  @include add-color(404145);
  @include add-color(ff0000);
}
```

output in CSS:

```
.custom-color--404145 {
  color: #404145;
}

.custom-color--ff0000 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Read more about it here: 
[Generate All Your Utility Classes with Sass Maps](https://frontstuff.io/generate-all-your-utility-classes-with-sass-maps)

Comment: this doesn't allow you to dynamically change the color you still have to update your sass each time you want to use a different class to adjust the color. Is there a way to let sass just grab a part of a class name and use it to set the color ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you want to do this but I think you can achieve similar by using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

For example:

HTML

```
<div class="custom-color" style="--red: #ff0000">Red</div>
<div class="custom-color" style="--green: #00ff00">Green</div>
<div class="custom-color" style="--blue: #0000ff">Blue</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-color {
  color:  var(--red); // or what color you want
}
```